# Entity Framework Mapping join table fields

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a join table that has a field in it that I need to get into an Entity and have it updatable.  I have the Table setup below, the column I need is "`PersonelleID`" in the "`Account`" table.  Now, there may be multiple, so in that case, there's a concept of primary (think of it as if you were a student who went from one school to another, you'd have the same account but multiple schools).

Any idea how I can bring this into the Entity world?  Generating the database ignores this field on the join table (probably because it doesn't know where to put it).

Trying to see what the best route to go is.

[image: Entity Problem]

Comment: Are you using the Model-First approach or Database-First. It is unclear from the question, since you mention `Generating the database ignores this field on the join table`. Are you generating the database from the model?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Database-First approach.

Comment: If you are generating the model from the database and your table contains an extra field (apart from the two Id's), the entity for it should be generated by EF (you shouldn't do anything special to achieve that). What version of EF are you using? Have you tried deleting your model and generating from scratch or are you trying to update an existing model?

Comment: Deleting and regenerating did it, but now I have a ton of other changes to redo.  Thanks though!

Comment: Sure. It might be tricky adding/removing/renaming fields and updating the model from the database. The safest way is to delete and re-add the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the Code-First approach you would create an entity for the join table that has foreign keys to both Account and School and your extra properties.

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set;}
}

public class AccountSchool
{
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("School")]
    public string CEEBCodeId { get; set; }

    public string PersonelleID { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    [Key]
    public string CEEBCodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

This is how I've done it and here's is an article explaining how to do it as well:
http://www.itq.nl/blogs/post/Code-First-Entity-Framework-Additional-properties-on-many-to-many-join-tables.aspx

Comment: I figured that'd be the way with code-first, but I am using a generated entity model.  Any way to do it in there?